# Allow default value to inout parameter

Tags: swift, inout

The title might be a little confusing, so let me break this to you.

In Swift, we can have functions with default parameter values, e.g:

```
func foo(value: Int = 32) { }
```

And we also can have In-Out parameters, e.g.

```
func foo(value: inout Int) { }
```

But, there is a way to have both? A inout parameter, that if it wasn't passed, we can create? This is particularly useful with recursive functions, and I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: Since inout is passed around by reference, I doubt there would be a way to create it like default value. Perhaps you can create one, before calling the recursive function by checking for it? What's the exact use case?

Answer (score 3):

Default parameters are mostly just a convenient shorthand for overloads. When you want to move beyond the basics, you just build the overload by hand, which allows you any level of complexity you want:

```
// The base-case version
func foo() {
    var value = 0
    foo(value: &value)
}

func foo(value: inout Int) { }
```

As a side note, be very careful with recursion in Swift. There's no tail-call optimization, so you can blow up the stack if the recursion is deep. The lack of elegant pattern matching makes recursive code much less elegant, and passing values by `inout` makes things harder on the optimzer. In most cases you'll want a loop (or to hide the loop in a higher-order non-recursive function like `map`).

Also, don't forget about nesting functions, which is helpful for hiding accumulator-style parameters.

```
func foo() {
    var value = 0

    func f() {
        // operate on value and recurse
        // no need for inout; and doesn't leak the implementation detail
    }

    f()
}
```